# TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Tags: django-models

Saving new_post throws the error. I haven't tinkered with the save method so I am wondering where is the error coming from.

```
def post(request, method="POST"):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_data = Post(request.POST)

        new_post = post_data.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: What is `Post`? At first sight it looks like it is not a `ModelForm`, but a model. A model has no `commit=` parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi thanks for clarifying that. Yes it's a model. I'm wondering how can I implement the "commit=False" functionality in models if it has no commit parameter.

Comment: But it makes no sense at all to have a commit parameter. Since it is the model object itself. A form has a `commit=False` to prevent one from saving it to the database already and thus post-process the model object, but here you *have* the model object.